# Tomcat 7, cannot disable web application autoDeploy

Tags: tomcat7, web-deployment

After deploying a web application, my Tomcat 7 server doesn't start anymore, signaling an exception during startup process.

So I tried to configure Tomcat to avoid to deploy the webapps at startup.
To do so, I've modified my `${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/server.xml` and add an `autoDeploy="false"` attribute to the `Host` node. (I've also verified that there are no `liveDeploy` attributes):

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
...
```

then I read about liveDeploy attribute with a slightly different behaviour, and to be sure I disabled it too:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" liveDeploy = "false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
...
```

The problem is that it seems to do nothing, and in the outuput I still see "Deploying configuration descriptor" lines, till the one that crashes Tomcat.

Here there is the server output; I've include the startup, a first application (MyFirstApplication) that is deployed correctly, and the last one that crashses the server.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.11.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.11"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.11.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.11\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.11\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\spring-roo-1.1.4.RELEASE\bin;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9.1\java\ant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2\java\maven\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\cmdutilities;.
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 411 ms
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.11
gen 14, 2013 3:08:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Informazioni: Deploying configuration descriptor MyFirstWebApp.xml from C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.11.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
gen 14, 2013 3:08:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
Informazioni: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[...]
Informazioni: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml from C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.11.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
gen 14, 2013 3:08:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
Informazioni: Deploying configuration descriptor MavenSpringHibernate.xml from C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.11.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-1"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want set deployOnStartup, not autoDeploy (or possibly both). There is no such setting of liveDeploy.

From the Tomcat 7 docs for Host [1]

> **autoDeploy**
>
> This flag value indicates if Tomcat should check periodically for new
>   or updated web applications while Tomcat is running. If true, Tomcat
>   periodically checks the appBase and xmlBase directories and deploys
>   any new web applications or context XML descriptors found. Updated web
>   applications or context XML descriptors will trigger a reload of the
>   web application. The flag's value defaults to true. See Automatic
>   Application Deployment for more information.
>
> **deployOnStartup**
>
> This flag value indicates if web applications from this host should be
>   automatically deployed when Tomcat starts. The flag's value defaults
>   to true. See Automatic Application Deployment for more information.

[1] http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html

Comment: Ok, that seems the right way. Just a clarification: if i disable deployOnStartup and autoDeploy, how would i explicitly trigger the deploy of an application?

Comment: You'd have to explicitly configure the manager app via a Context element in server.xml and then use that to deploy additional WAR files and/or directories. Note the manager will not list any apps in CATALINA_BASE/webapps for you to choose from.

Comment: to deploy directory using "Executing Manager Commands With Ant" has problem related "java.io.IOException" in Tomcat6 + Apache-ant1.8.2 case